# Jump to nested elements within ajax assembled structure

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Hey so I'm not sure if this has any easy or good solution, but I figured I'd post here and find out if there's something I'm not thinking of.

Basically we have a bunch of data that's nested in logical groups (not necessarily reflected in the database architecture), and it's being loaded and navigated by way of dynamic ajax loads.  Think nested accordions (http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) where each accordion element's content is loaded via an ajax call which loads sub-accordions, that may load sub-sub-accordions via ajax, and so on..

The reason for this is that we are navigating a large volume of content and can't afford to put all of it on the page at once.

So, the question is how to jump directly to an element that is nested sufficiently deep so as not to be on the page yet?

For example:  If I wanted to hotlink to a block of content that was 3 levels deep on a page that only has 1 level actually loaded and all I have is the id of the block of content, not the parents. I would need to trigger the ajax load of the correct parents in order to have the element I want.  Triggering is easy once you have the path.  So how to deduce the path when it is essentially arbitrary in relation to data?

Caching the potential hierarchies of paths is the best we've come up with, but I'd love to find a way to avoid having one more thing to keep current in this system.

Ideas?

Comment: "a bunch of data that's nested in logical groups (not necessarily reflected in the database architecture)" - so where and how _is_ the relationship stored?

Comment: Well, you should somehow implement loading of as many levels as you desire, not just one by one. If you have child ID, then in server side you can figure out all parents and return all of them combined at once.

Comment: Good question @VolkerK.  It's usually stored as a relationship between two tables in the database, however a single child can have multiple parents so there's not a set path to trace back.  And in some situations the parent-child relations exist as 'group by' on a column.  In some cases, tables that are required for the parent-child relationship are not represented at all in the interface.

Comment: @algiecas it's an interesting proposition.  I'm not sure if it can be done given our current structure.  We've essentially engineered these child elements to be highly reusable and dependent on an ajax request.  But it may come down to some type of modified structure to accomplish just this.

Answer (score 1):

You could also make sure your hotlink contains the child. Especially when a child can have multiple parents. For example: http://www.domain.com/page/!#parent/parent/child